std::variant Compilation Errors When Using Custom Random Engine Wrapper in C++
I'm working on a C++ project where I have implemented a RandomEngineWrapper class to encapsulate various random number engines using std::variant. However, I encounter compilation errors when trying to use this wrapper in conjunction with std::visit.
no matching function for call to 'std::variant<std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 16807, 0, 2147483647>, std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 16807, 0, 2147483647>, std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 48271, 0, 2147483647>, std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 32, 624, 397, 31, 2567483615, 11, 4294967295, 7, 2636928640, 15, 4022730752, 18, 1812433253>, std::mersenne_twister_engine<long long unsigned int, 64, 312, 156, 31, 13043109905998158313, 29, 6148914691236517205, 17, 8202884508482404352, 37, 18444473444759240704, 43, 6364136223846793005>, std::subtract_with_carry_engine<unsigned int, 24, 10, 24>, std::subtract_with_carry_engine<long long unsigned int, 48, 5, 12>, std::discard_block_engine<std::subtract_with_carry_engine<unsigned int, 24, 10, 24>, 223, 23>, std::discard_block_engine<std::subtract_with_carry_engine<long long unsigned int, 48, 5, 12>, 389, 11>, std::shuffle_order_engine<std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 16807, 0, 2147483647>, 256> >::variant(std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 16807, 0, 2147483647>)'


no matching function for call to 'visit(generateRandomIndex<std::vector<int> >(const std::vector<int>&, ENGINE, DISTRIBUTION)::<lambda(auto:27&)>, std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 16807, 0, 2147483647>&)'


#include <random>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

enum class ENGINE {
    DEFAULT_RANDOM_ENGINE,
    MINSTD_RAND0,
    MINSTD_RAND,
    MT19937,
    MT19937_64,
    RANLUX24_BASE,
    RANLUX48_BASE,
    RANLUX24,
    RANLUX48,
    KNUTH_B,
    RANDOM_DEVICE
};

enum class DISTRIBUTION {
    UNIFORM_INT,
};

std::random_device rd;

class RandomEngineWrapper {
private:
    std::variant<
        std::default_random_engine,
        std::minstd_rand0,
        std::minstd_rand,
        std::mt19937,
        std::mt19937_64,
        std::ranlux24_base,
        std::ranlux48_base,
        std::ranlux24,
        std::ranlux48,
        std::knuth_b
    > engine_variant;

public:
    template <typename T>
    RandomEngineWrapper(T&& rng) : engine_variant(std::forward<T>(rng)) {}

    template <typename T>
    T& get() {
        return std::get<T>(engine_variant);
    }
};

RandomEngineWrapper getEngine(ENGINE engine) {
    switch (engine) {
        case ENGINE::DEFAULT_RANDOM_ENGINE:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::default_random_engine(rd()));
        case ENGINE::MINSTD_RAND0:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::minstd_rand0(rd()));
        case ENGINE::MINSTD_RAND:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::minstd_rand(rd()));
        case ENGINE::MT19937:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::mt19937(rd()));
        case ENGINE::MT19937_64:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::mt19937_64(rd()));
        case ENGINE::RANLUX24_BASE:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::ranlux24_base(rd()));
        case ENGINE::RANLUX48_BASE:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::ranlux48_base(rd()));
        case ENGINE::RANLUX24:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::ranlux24(rd()));
        case ENGINE::RANLUX48:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::ranlux48(rd()));
        case ENGINE::KNUTH_B:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::knuth_b(rd()));
        case ENGINE::RANDOM_DEVICE:
        default:
            return RandomEngineWrapper(std::mt19937(rd())); // Default case
    }
}

auto getDistribution(DISTRIBUTION distribution, int size) {
    switch (distribution) {
        case DISTRIBUTION::UNIFORM_INT:
            return std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, size - 1);
        default:
            return std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, size - 1); // Default case
    }
}

template <typename Container>
int generateRandomIndex(const Container& container, ENGINE engineChoice, DISTRIBUTION distributionChoice) {
    auto engineWrapper = getEngine(engineChoice);
    auto dist = getDistribution(distributionChoice, container.size());
    
    int index = 0;
    std::visit([&](auto& engine) {
        index = dist(engine);
    }, engineWrapper.get<std::default_random_engine>());

    return index;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> myVector = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int index = generateRandomIndex(myVector, ENGINE::MT19937, DISTRIBUTION::UNIFORM_INT);
    std::cout << "Random index: " << index << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

The std::visit call in the generateRandomIndex function produces the error:
no matching function for call to 'visit(generateRandomIndex<std::vector<int> >(const std::vector<int>&, ENGINE, DISTRIBUTION)::<lambda(auto:27&)>, std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 16807, 0, 2147483647>&)'

Additionally, I receive an error related to the std::variant constructor when trying to initialize RandomEngineWrapper with various random engines.
Why am I getting these errors, and how can I correctly use std::variant and std::visit to achieve my goal of wrapping various random engines and using them to generate random indices?
###Additional Information:###

I'm using std::variant to wrap different types of random number engines.
The RandomEngineWrapper class is designed to abstract away the details of different random engines.
I need to generate random indices in a container using a specified random engine and distribution.
Any insights into resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated.


error message are more readable when formatted like code

Not so much with this error. variant sucks if you give it more than a couple non-trivial members, so the error message is doomed to be ugly.

The error about the std::variant constructor is caused by having two copies of std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 16807, 0, 2147483647> in the variant, one from std::default_random_engine and the other from std::minstd_rand0. Removing std::default_random_engine from the variant fixes it.
The error in the std::visit() call is because it expects a variant as the second argument, not an actual engine type. This can be solved by adding a member function to RandomEngineWrapper that calls std::visit (based on std::variant::visit() from C++26):
template <typename Visitor>
decltype(auto) RandomEngineWrapper::useEngine(Visitor&& vis) {
    return std::visit(std::forward<Visitor>(vis), engine_variant);
}

which can be used in generateRandomIndex() like this:
int index;
engineWrapper.useEngine([&](auto& engine) {
    index = dist(engine);
});

